# bash multiple php command sleep

Tags: bash

I have a list of commands like this, only about 30 pieces

```
1 nohup php /home/u642830940/domains/domain.com/public_html/admin.php -p --dispatch=advanced_import.import.import --preset_id=$preset_id > /dev/null
```

There is a bash script like this

```
#!/bin/bash

commands_str=$(/usr/bin/php /home/u642830940/domains/idata.lv/public_html/parsing/spark cron1 foxway)

IFS='&' read -ra commands <<< "$(echo "$commands_str" | tail -n +4)"

max_commands=7

for command in "${commands[@]}"; do
    commands_total=$(ps aux | grep php | wc -l || printf "0")

    while [ $commands_total -ge $max_commands ]; do
        if [ $commands_total -ge $max_commands ]; then
            echo -e "maximum number of commands reached: ${commands_total}/${max_commands}. waiting... \n"
        fi
        wait -n
        commands_total=$(ps aux | grep php | wc -l || printf "0")
    done

    echo -e "starting new command: $command \n"
    bash -c "$command 2>&1 & disown"
done
```

but over time, randomly, maybe in a day or maybe in 2 hours the system itself will kill or the script just goes to sleep. I am 100% sure that there is no error in these scripts, since if it is restarted bypassing the script, it is executed. What is the problem and how to fix it. And yes, 2 commands can take about 40 minutes to complete.

```
php /home/u642830940/domains/domain.com/public_html/admin.php -p --dispatch=advanced_import.import.import --preset_id=$preset_id > /dev/null &
```

But script anyway Sleep or system kill

Comment: Why do you need the `if` statement? It's the same condition as the `while` condition, so you'll never get there if the condition is false.

Comment: I suggest using a tool like GNU Parallel to run commands in parallel.

Comment: Don't use `echo -e`, use `printf`.

Comment: `wait` can only wait for its own children that are running in the background. When you use `bash -c "$command 2>&1 & disown"`, the command is running in a grandchild. So your script is running continuously, never waiting for anything. You may be hitting the CPU limit.

Comment: @Barmarand what option then just run the commands and exit the script

Answer (score 0):

Don't run the command in a nested call to `bash`, because you can't wait for that. Use `eval` to execute it in the current shell.

```
eval "$command 2>&1" &
```

And don't disown it, that also makes it not a child of the current shell.

Comment: but it doesn't matter to me what it displays, I need a script, I just need to run all the scripts and exit

Comment: This has nothing to do with what it displays. This is needed so the `wait` command in your loop will work correctly.

Comment: Yes, those commands that are made up to 10 minutes work with your remark now without fail. BUT long commands sometimes do not have time to monitor the situation through ps aux found the following line and come to the conclusion that all the same I need to untie from the current script at least these 2 commands
u642830+ 2091586 0.0 0.0 221364 976 ? S 05:40 0:00 timeout -s 9 1800 /bin/sh /home/u642830940/domains/domain.com/public_html/parsing/cron.sh

Comment: I can't change the launch of the cron, hosting doesn't allow it. I suspect that these 30 minutes are set just because the script should run every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
commands_str=$(/usr/bin/php /home/u642830940/domains/idata.lv/public_html/parsing/spark cron1 foxway)

IFS='&' read -ra commands <<< "$(echo "$commands_str" | tail -n +4)"

max_commands=7

parallel -j $max_commands ::: "${commands[@]}"
```

You might even be able to do something like:

```
max_commands=7

/usr/bin/php /home/u642830940/domains/idata.lv/public_html/parsing/spark cron1 foxway |
  tail -n +4 | perl -pe 's/&/\n/g' |
  parallel -j $max_commands
```